# Project nestsed array elements in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with documents like this

```
"_id": ObjectId('55f02a779e6efb8'),
"msgId": "5fdf509c-5229-4e7c-87ff",
"statuses": [
    {
        "state": "QUEUED",
        "timestamp": ISODate('2013-10-08T13:13:38.000Z')
    },
    {
        "state": "PENDING",
        "timestamp": ISODate('2013-10-08T13:13:49.000Z')
    },
    {
        "state": "DELIVERED",
        "timestamp": ISODate('2013-10-08T13:13:57.000Z')
    }
]
```

I want to use project for assigning the last 2 (embedded docs) values of the nested array (the array size is not static) so as to use them in a group operation in later step.

I want sth like $slice(aggregation) but it is still not supported in the version of MongoDB I use (3.0.6).

Is there any way to access the 2 last elements of the array by their index and if not is there any other solution?

Comment: There is already a basic [`$slice`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) that will retrieve the last two elements without any other conditions.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I don't think I can use it in an aggregation operation.

Comment: No you cannot. Why do you need it in aggregation? What is the overall purpose? Not very clear here. It's possible, but it is very messy. Would be better if your explained why the "last two" are important.

Comment: I want to group the documents by their current and the previous state and also other fields.

Comment: Try and be a little more "literal" in what you are asking. What do you mean "current and last date"? Are these always the last two properties of the array in order? What if there is only "one" array entry? What is the actual "end result" you want to get out of these two "possible" items. This is what makes a "clear" question. Please "edit" your question with all the details, as they do no belong in comments. Then it is clear for people to find a solution. Don't say "what you think needs to be done", but say "what you need as a result".

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but as I am sure for the details (like that the minimum array size is 2, and that I always want the last 2 elements), I think it is clear what i want as a result (i.e access on the last 2 elements of a nested array). So I don't find any reason to pollute my question with logic detail of the work I want to do. No offence :)

Comment: The "advice" is "explain what you want". You are asking for "slice" in aggregation. It is not really practical until the next release. So instead of asking that question then ask what you really want to achieve from getting the last two elements in the first place. Your question is not practically answerable under the current restrictions without walking though all array elements of a predetermined known length. Also when the current [top scored answerer](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mongodb/topusers) in the tag you are asking offers "advice", then you really should listen. No offence.

Comment: Ok I will reconsider the problem, with the "predetermined known length" and all the other things in mind and I will come back with an edit.Thanks!